# Console time разные показания! Парсинг на стороне клиента. Что быстрее?

Tags: javascript, парсер

Здравствуйте,
Есть две структуры данных, пытаюсь разобрать, какой вид быстрее будет парситься на клиенте:

a)

```
data = {
   caption: ['1stCaption', '2stCaption', ...],
   name: ['1stName', '2ndName', ...],
}
```

б)

```
data = [{
   caption: '1sCaption',
   name: '1stName',
},{
   caption: '2ndCaption',
   name: '2ndName',
}]
```

Вот как я делал замер: https://jsfiddle.net/Serginyo90/37wvkfku/

Comment: не копайте себе яму, пользуйте второй вариант.

Comment: @teran первый в два раза меньше весит. И это не моя прихоть, а тех. дира

Comment: чем вес измеряете? по вашему скрипту у меня в разница в одну десятую мс (то что пишет в консоль)

Comment: @teran ну у Вас разница по скорости парсинга. А вес данных и так видно что в 2 раза меньше, т.к. в 1ом случае наименование свойства объекта указывается один раз, в отличии от 2ого, где в каждом объекте надо будет дублировать наименование свойства.

Comment: вы про какой размер то говорите, передачи данных клиенту, или занимаемой памяти при работе?. Коли про "парсинг" дак, наверное, про второе, но тут я бы не был так уверен, что движок внутри себя при выполнении хранит все именно так как вы это видите в коде.

Comment: первый вариант может быть меньше при передаче данных, но он совершенно не удобен в работе. Так что либо делать маппинг к нормальному виду при получении, либо хз. Во втором варианте `caption` и `name` всегда можно сократить до `c` и `n`, к примеру, что уменьшит объем данных. но еще больше его уменьшит сжатие при передаче.

Comment: Оба варианта сжимаются gzip'ом в примерно один и тот же размер плюс-минус несколько байт. Нечего экономить на спичках